# Laravel authentication form issue (redirects to home before showing register page)

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-form

I'm new to laravel, and I'm making a website as my software development project on laravel 5.1. I'm stuck at the authentication form. I tried using the sample register and login form provided in laravel documentation and it worked all right. But when I replaced it with my own designed form, It redirects to home page and doesn't show the register page at all. My form -

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
    Personal Health Assistant: Home

@endsection

@section('head')
<script>
    $(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>

@endsection

@section('content')
<div style="height: 100px"></div>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#"  id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" class="active" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form id="login-form" action="/auth/login" method="POST" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form id="register-form" action="/auth/register" method="POST" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="name" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

My route file-

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/symptomchecker', function () {
    return view('pages.symptomchecker');
});
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

/*Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('pages.login');
});

Route::get('/signup', function () {
    return view('pages.signup');
});*/

Route::get('/consult-doc', function () {
    return view('pages.consult');
});

});
```

Comment: Do you mean when you try to register the form redirects you to this url /home?

Comment: when I enter localhost:8000/auth/register in browser it redirects me to localhost:8000/home

Comment: Maybe you are already logged in as a user, hit this up in your browser localhost:8000/auth/logout then try to register again

Comment: Thanks, it worked, you saved my life!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that Saad answered the question and that the user was already logged in. In the future you can check to determine if the user is already logged in by:

blade:

```
@if (Auth::check())
    {{ The User is logged in }}
@endif
```

or (non blade):

```
 if (Auth::check()) {
    echo 'The User is logged in';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I watched a couple of videos later. Isn't using middleware better?